# Configuring a Jenkins cloud to use Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm working through the AWS Jenkins tutorial on AWS's website and have gotten stuck. I'm at the point where I need to fill out my EC2 credentials but I'm not sure what to fill out the fields with. Is "Name" a generic name Jenkins will call this or is it the EC2 instance I have running on my AWS account. Are the EC2 credentials my login information or something else? It's all a little vague and I thought I'd come here to seek some clarificationon these fields and the others, thanks! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name: should be the instance-id but you can use also another name.

Amazon EC2 Credentials: click on add - Jenkins and you will see some options:

- Username with password : you can use this method if you know your username and password for accessing the instance.
- AWS Credential: you have to specify  Access Key ID and Secret Access Key
- SSH username with private key: the login information are usually `root/ubuntu/ec2-user` (depends from the instance type) At the end, you have to specify your pem key (you should have downloaded it once the instance has been created)

You can ignore the other methods (Certificate, Secret file, Secret text)

[image: Amazon EC2 Plugin]

Answer (score 2):

While you can use access+secret for a user, the better way to handle this is IAM roles. Definitely keep on working with user credentials for now, but if you start exploring further, look into IAM roles and Amazon Machine Images (AMIs). With AMIs, roles, and an auto-scaling group, you can create an elastic pool of build machines to help keep costs down. Particularly useful is destroying all build instances for dev environments during the evening and weekends (or changing to some smaller, cheaper instance type). This isn't trivial, but it saved us tons of money when we were running 100+ build nodes. Anywho, just some food for thought for the future.

Comment: [AWS Elastic Beanstalk now supports custom AMIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html), so this would be a terrific service to use for scalable build environments with minimal operations hassle.